# Why am I getting a RPC server error using a SaveFileDialogue in a WinForms app?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, savefiledialog, first-chance-exception

I'm getting an error when I try to use the SaveFileDialogue in a WinForms app.  I must be missing something as the error makes no sense (to me!)!

The error is: "First-chance exception at 0x000007fefc99cacd in TestProject.exe: 0x000006BA: The RPC server is unavailable."

The error occurs when this line runs: "if (SD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)".

Here is my code:

```
var SD = new SaveFileDialog();
SD.Filter = "PDF (*.pdf)|*.pdf|Show All Files (*.*)|*.*";
SD.FileName = "Untitled";
SD.Title = "Save As";
if (SD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
// DO SOMETHING HERE
}
```

Edit: I'm saving the file locally, but the error occurs before the user has even picked a location to save, it occurs at the point where I try to show the dialogue for the user to pick the location!

Comment: where are you trying to save the file? somewhere across a network, or locally?

Comment: are you saving that file at the local machine filesystem ?

Comment: See my edit: I'm saving locally...

Comment: Use SysInternals' AutoRuns utility to disable cranky shell extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you have activated some flag in the Exceptions Debug Menu.
Try to reset to default configuration going to Debug -> Exceptions -> Reset All

Comment: I have activated the flag to break on all exceptions (caught and uncaught), but my question is really, why is there an exception and how do I stop it?  I don't want to simply ignore the fact that it's there! :)

Comment: It is an exception caught inside the SaveFileDialog and your code has nothing to worry about. If you try your application in release mode you don't have any exception. Right? [Some background here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx)

Comment: OK, I'm willing to admit that I might have been a bit too proactive on this one, if... You can point me to something which explains why the SaveFileDialogue has an exception?  It seems unlikely that a basic control which hasn't been modified for donkeys has an exception in it! :-S  Surely MS know better than this ;-)

Comment: And, how the hell to I get more points on here?  I'm just trying to get to 200 points, but I'm dying down here at 30!

Comment: The only way is: Post questions, accept answers, post (right) answers to other users questions, help the community with edits, take your time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: I'm getting the same error but for me happens in debug and also in release... any more clues?